# Cannot create property '_locals' on string

Tags: node.js

Hello im trying to  select from my databas however it [Object,object]. Then I searched around and got the answer to stringify, however now I got a new issues saying "Cannot create property '_locals' on string " anybody knows how to solve it?

```
app.get('/behandlare', function(req, res){
pool.connect(function(err, table, done){ 
    if(err) {
        return console.error('error fetching staff from table', err);
    }
    table.query('SELECT * FROM public.staff', function(err, result){
        if(err){
            return console.error('error runnig query', err);
        }
        res.render('behandlare.ejs', JSON.stringify({staff: result.rows}));
        done();
    });
});
});
```

[image]

.ejs

```
          <div class = "ruta">
        <a href = "calender"><img src="img/spakvinna.jpg" alt="" style="width:400px;height:250px;"><%= name %></a>
        <p class="sida2"></p>
      </div>
```

Comment: do you have the stack trace or any additional information about the error? would be easier to read things if you put formatted text instead of screen shots too

Comment: node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1003

Answer (score 4):

OK, so i'm assuming that `res.render('behandlare.ejs', JSON.stringify({staff: result.rows}));` actually requires an object in express and not a string... so instead of doing stringify just pass the object. Ummm... I assume that you might be using it in a wrong way in the template you are using or something of that sort but if it gets you back to the previous error maybe that was the real problem and you need to see how to solve that.

Comment: If I dont stringify I get [Object, object]

Comment: you get [Object, object] because you are probably trying to use that directly in the template... show me the .ejs file please and show me where you are getting [Object, object]

Comment: no clue what you are after, but this is how I get [Object, object]

Comment: im trying to figure out what you are doing and where and how are you getting [Object, object] please provide info on what you expect to happen show us what's happening and how exactly are you trying to use `staff`

Answer (score 2):

Inside `res.render` has to be an ***object literal***

```
// option 1
const myObj = {
  obj: req.body,
  hats:["white","grey","black"]
};
res.render( 'success', { myObj } )

// or option 2
res.render( 'success', { myObj: req.body } )
```

It have to be *literally an object*

---

##### Object Definition

[How-to define](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) (and create) a JavaScript object with an object literal

```
const myObj = {
  firstName:"John", 
  lastName:"Doe", 
  age:50, 
  eyeColor:"blue"
};
```